# How do I pass the same variable to more than one View in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to pass the same value to multiple views but I am only able to pass it to one (pages.days).

When I hit the days/{{$id}} end point I get the value of $id back and It displays in my page by not the appdashTest blade file

How do I get the value of $id to display in both views at once?

### Controller

```
    public function show($id)
{
    $allDays = Days::all();
    return view('pages.days', ['trip_id' => $id])
                ->with(['allDays' => $allDays])
                ->with('layouts.appdashTest');
}
```

### Days.blade.php

```
    <h1>Trip Id {{$trip_id}}</h1>
<form action="/days" method="post" role="form">
    <legend>Create New Days</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value={{$trip_id}}>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">New Days</button>
</form>
```

### appdashTest.blade.php

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="text-center"><a href="#"><i class="trvlrs-calendar"></i></a></li>
                        <li class="text-center"><a href="{{$trip_id}}/invitation"><i class="trvlrs-mail"></i></a></li>
                        <li class="text-center"><a href="/discovery"><i class="trvlrs-location"></i></a></li>
                        <li class="text-center"><a href="#"><i class="trvlrs-banknote"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
```

Comment: Is `appdashTest.blade.php` included into your `Days.blade.php` template?

Comment: use a view composer.  you can read about it in these [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views)

Comment: The appdashTest.blade.php and Days.blade.php are two separate pages When I go the days pages it goes to localhost:8000/days/1. I have a navbar that should take me to days/{{$trip_id}}/invitation where $id = 1. Unfortunately, I keep on getting an error that says $id is undefined, But in the days page $trip_id works just fine.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `->with('layouts.appdashTest')` in your code? the `with()` is used to pass variables to the view. You shouldn't have to do anything special to make it work, something is wrong with your code. You may have to read how views works in Laravel, for example the view `extends` the layout, here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#extending-a-layout

Comment: Yes, I was testing it out to see if that would work but it didn't. I was hoping that would let me pass the variables to both views while only returning one.

Answer (score 1):

Include your file `appdashTest.blade.php` like this:

```
@include('appdashTest.blade.php', ['trip_id' => $trip_id])
```

#### Controller

```
public function show($id)
{
    return view('pages.days', [
        'trip_id' => $id,
        'allDays' => Days::all(),
    ]);
}
```

#### Days.blade.php

```
<h1>Trip Id {{$trip_id}}</h1>
<form action="/days" method="post" role="form">
    <legend>Create New Days</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value={{$trip_id}}>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">New Days</button>
</form>

<!-- Add this where you want your appdashTest.blade.php -->
@include('appdashTest.blade.php', ['trip_id' => $trip_id])
```

#### appdashTest.blade.php

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="text-center"><a href="#"><i class="trvlrs-calendar"></i></a></li>
    <li class="text-center"><a href="{{$trip_id}}/invitation"><i class="trvlrs-mail"></i></a></li>
    <li class="text-center"><a href="/discovery"><i class="trvlrs-location"></i></a></li>
    <li class="text-center"><a href="#"><i class="trvlrs-banknote"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Still getting this error  "Undefined variable: trip_id "

Comment: I apologize so the Days.blade.php and the appdashTest.blade.php is one file. The appdashTest.blade is basically the navbar and should link me to the invite page.